# How can I trigger ScrollView Proxy from a parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui

My scenario is simple, I have a parent view that has a button and a child view that has a timeline. What I would like to do is **when I click my parent view button to move my child view timeline view to the top**. I have been able to do that but only if the button is already in that same child view as the timeline view, I can not seem to get it to work when clicking the parent view button. If you look at my code below Button B works because it is in the same view as the TimeLine, however how can I make it so that when I click Button A in the parent view I can get my timeline to go to the top like in Button B ? Any suggestions would be great. My code below will also work in Xcode.

```
struct ExampleUpdateListBind: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Button A")
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("By Clicking this one my timeline child view should scroll to the top")
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            MYListExamples()
        }
    }
}



struct MYListExamples: View {

    var myList = ["X First Row","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam",
                  "Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"
                  ,"Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"
                  ,"Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"]
    var body: some View {

        let result = myList.sorted {
            $0 > $1
        }
        ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
            Button("Button B") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(result[0], anchor: .top)
            }
            List {
                ForEach(result) { i in
                    Text(i)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to keep some sort of state or publisher in the parent view that is passed down to the child view, which will most likely observe it via `onChange` or `onReceive`.

Here's a very simple version:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine //possibly necessary if using a Publisher-based solution

struct ExampleUpdateListBind: View {
    @State private var send = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Button A")
                .onTapGesture {
                    send = Date()
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            MYListExamples(receive: send)
        }
    }
}



struct MYListExamples: View {
    var receive : Date
    
    var myList = ["X First Row","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam",
                  "Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"
                  ,"Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"
                  ,"Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam","Joseph","Adam","John","Abe","Joseph","Adam"]
    var body: some View {

        let result = myList.sorted {
            $0 > $1
        }
        ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
            Button("Button B") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(result[0], anchor: .top)
            }
            .onChange(of: receive) { _ in
                proxy.scrollTo(result[0], anchor: .top)
            }
            List {
                ForEach(result, id: \.self) { I in //note that in a real-world case, we wouldn't want to use \.self with strings that have duplicate values like the data provided in the original question above
                    Text(i)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Other solutions could include passing a reference to a Publisher and using `onReceive` or storing the state in an `ObservableObject` that gets passed to the child view -- the premise is the same no matter what the scenario.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot that solved the issue .